# Pagination Wordpress in Custom Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Hi I hope someone can help with this.
I'm building a web site using wordpress, but I created my custom themes.
I just have basic knowledge of php and i managed to build the home page which show the latest 4 post.

This is the code that i use to show the last and the second-last post. Just using an offset and skipping one post every time to show the previous.

LATEST POST SCRIPT

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('cat=1,4,5&numberposts=1&offset=0'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "1") { break; } else { ?>

<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php $count1++; } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

SECOND LAST POST SCRIPT

```
    </span></td>
        <td colspan="8" rowspan="2" valign="top" class="blog_text">
  <?php 

query_posts('showposts=1'); ?>
  <?php $posts = get_posts('cat=1,4,5&numberposts=1&offset=1'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
  <?php static $count2 = 0; if ($count2 == "1") { break; } else { ?>


  <?php the_content(); ?>

  <?php $count2++; } ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope this part help to understand, because i'm working in local so i can't show the website for now.

Now my problem is how i can dynamic implement the pagination? so if the first page show the post 1,2,3,4
i need to create a dynamic pagination which would allow me on clicking "previous posts" or the number of the page
will show the post number 4,5,6,7.
I've already had a look on the tutorial for dynamic pagination but i can't understand how i can do it, as i'm working on wordpress
and my script are different! As i said i have basic knowledge of PHP so if someone could explain me how to do with my code would be perfect!
Probably i don't need the foreach because this was a code found to show from post 1 to post 4 for example, and i changed to show just one!
I basically can't use a normal loop because the post that i have to show are in diferrent postion so i need separate code!

I hope i could explained myself! Thank you to everyone for any help.

Comment: I tried this http://designphiliconline.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/wordpress-custom-post-type-pagination.html?showComment=1378003312469#c8786213242726004295

it load correctly the page but the posts don't change!

Comment: Try these are the wordpress Pagination function - posts_nav_link()
`next_posts_link()
previous_posts_link()
get_next_posts_link()
get_previous_posts_link()
paginate_links()`

Comment: `<?php query_posts('showposts=1'); ?>` Why are you using this? You should be using `WP_Query` **not** `query_posts`. Secondly, `showposts` has been long time depreciated. You should be using `posts_per_page`  Enable debug in wp-config.php, this should tell you as well

Comment: So how should i modify my code with wp_query and posts_per_page? are they using the same arguments? thank you!

Comment: I found this http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination and i think is my problem, because i'm changing the offset so i can't get pagination. But i really can't understand how to apply to my code. Would be another way to you just one loop in my index and not changing the offset? because right now i need to use 4 different loop for each post displayed in the index!